# RNCGeolocation.requestAuthorization undefined not a function

Tags: reactjs, react-native, geolocation, android-manifest, android-permissions

I can not build for android on react-native. I am getting error about geolocation. All spermissions added to AndroidManifest like the code below; Do you have any idea, how can i solve this issue?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

[screen shot about geolocation error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AvRl2.png)

Answer (score 1):

- RequestAuthorization work only on ios: https://github.com/Agontuk/react-native-geolocation-service#async-requestauthorizationauthorizationlevel-ios-only
- You need to use `PermissionsAndroid` or [react-native-permissions](https://github.com/zoontek/react-native-permissions)
  to handle on android https://github.com/Agontuk/react-native-geolocation-service#usage